# Can a Azure function write back data to synapse database

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, powerapps-canvas

I am new to azure stack, so my please bear with my question.

I have a synapse database and I have a powerapp that reads data from synapse database. So, powerapps cannot writeback to synapse database. So I am thinking of developing a azure function with https trigger and integrate with the powerapp button on click functionality. So, my question is CAN AZURE FUNCTION WRITE BACK TO SYNAPSE DATABASE?

PS: I have tried the same with logic apps, with new row in sql trigger, and it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a library for connecting to the synapse database that does not need to be installed but can be loaded in your application then yes Function Apps can write to the synapse DB as long as the connectivity is there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).